# Can someone tell me how does this work ? (C programming)

Tags: c, increment

```
int m, n, j;
n=16;
j=15;
m = n++ -j+10;
printf("%d", m);
```

Output: 11.

Here, first, the old value of `n` is given to `m` and then it is incremented so the new value i get is 17 and then the expression is solved i.e. `j+10` = 25 then the new value of n is subtracted by 25 i.e 17-25.
Am i right ? but the answer doesn't match the output `11`.
Then how does this work ?
And also, i am new to programming and started learning C. Which book will you suggest is the best for me ? As I've no programming experience.
Thank you.

Comment: no value is asigned to m unless the complete calculation on the right side (that's why we talk about a R-Value, R stands for right) has been finished. here m is L-Value (L for left).

Comment: `m` is `16-15+10`, because `n++ == 16`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m = n++ -j+10;` is same as

```
m = n -j+10;
n = n + 1; // m is 11.
```

If it was `++n` It would be

```
n = n + 1;
m = n -j+10; //m is 12.
```

> then the expression is solved i.e. j+10 = 25

No. It would  be `-j+10` = -5

My suggestion is, **dont write complex expression unless you are completely sure what you are writing.**

Comment: I understood. Helped alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few things wrong there.

1. `n++` will increment `n` and return the original result, so you've then got `m = 16 ...`.
2. `-j` so you've got `m = 16 - 15 ...`.
3. `+10` so you've got `m = 16 - 15 + 10`.

Now the last time I did maths that would come out as `m = 11` like you're seeing.

If you wanted it to be `m = 17 - (15 + 10)` then you wanted:

```
int m, n, j;
n=16;
j=15;
m = ++n -(j+10);
printf("%d", m);
```

Comment: I understood. Helped alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in fact the post increment operation is done on n after the operation...
you have 16-15+10 = 11
but if you print n you should have 17.

to begin, you can read some book on basics but this example is not simple; it include the precedence of operator which can be tricky.

begin simple... it's quite simple to write unreadable code in c.
http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node4.html

hope it helps

Comment: I understood. Helped alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`n++` first returns the value of `n` and then increments it.
 so, the actual computation that takes place is `m = 16 - 15 + 10` which is 11

i think what you want is:

```
m = (n+1) - (j+10);
```

the use of the `++` operator is to increment the value of `n` for future use after you use it's current value to compute `m`.

Comment: But where is the incrementation done ?
The value of `n=16` and `j=15`. Then what is the use of `++` here ?

Comment: n++ increments n not m, if your print the value of n you'll see that it's 17

Comment: I understood. Helped alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for `m`, first of all calculate `n - j + 10` and assign it to `m`. After that `n++` is executed.

at the end `n = 17`, `m = 11`

Comment: I understood. Helped alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're making two incorrect interpretations.

Firstly, as indicated in other answers, `n++` only increments `n` after the entire expression has been evaluated.

Secondly, you have `-j+10`.  This is not equal to `-(j+10)`, so it is wrong to say that `j+10` is `25` and you are looking a `something - 25`.  Another way of view `-j+10` is `10-j`.

Comment: I understood. Helped alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question about a good book - you probably want to consider learning C++ instead of just plain old C, since C++ is a superset of C.  And for C++ you need to get Bjarne Stroustrup's 'The C++ Programming Language'.  It's easy enough to read and will last a long time on your bookshelf as a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression `m = n++ -j+10;`
The compiler treats  the expression as `m=  n++ ((-j)+10)`
As the intialized values of n and j are `n = 16` and `j = 15`.  We have `m = 16++ ((-15)+10)`.         We  get output as `11`.
After the expression is executed `n` will be incremented.

Answer (score -1):

`n` is incremented **after** its value is used in the expression which ends up in `m`.

Answer (score -1):

`n++` is **post incrementation**. It only increments the value of `n` after doing: `m = n++ -j+10;`

`++n` is pre incrementation. It increments the value of `n` before calculing m. `m = ++n -j+10;`